# Flex dynamic tabs using ViewStack

Tags: apache-flex, dynamic, tabs

I'm having problems creating dynamic tabs
here's my code:

mxml:

```
<s:TabBar x="1" y="1" height="32" width="100%" dataProvider="{tabHolder}" chromeColor="#EF8B01"/>
    <mx:ViewStack x="2" y="34" id="tabHolder" width="100%" height="214" creationPolicy="all">        
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Home" width="100%" height="100%">
            <mx:Image x="6" y="8" height="181" width="402"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>           
    </mx:ViewStack>
```

as:

```
 var newTab:NavigatorContent = new NavigatorContent();
            newTab.label = "Dynamic";                                   
            var lab:Label = new Label();
            lab.text = "Dynamic context";                                   
            newTab.addChild(lab);

            tabHolder.addChild(newTab);
```

tab wasn't added, what is wrong?

Comment: Did you have a chance to try out the answer I posted below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following worked for me. The only thing I changed was using the `addElement()` method instead of `addChild()` to add the tab to the viewstack.

**MXML:**

```
<mx:Button id="myButton" label="Add Tab" click="myButton_clickHandler(event)" />
<s:TabBar x="1" y="31" height="32" width="100%" dataProvider="{tabHolder}" chromeColor="#EF8B01"/>
<mx:ViewStack x="2" y="64" id="tabHolder" width="100%" height="214" creationPolicy="all">        
  <s:NavigatorContent label="Home" width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:Image x="6" y="8" height="181" width="402"/>
  </s:NavigatorContent>           
</mx:ViewStack>
```

**ActionScript:**

```
protected function myButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  var newTab:NavigatorContent = new NavigatorContent();
  newTab.label = "Dynamic";                                   
  var lab:Label = new Label();
  lab.text = "Dynamic context";                                   
  newTab.addElement(lab);
  tabHolder.addElement(newTab);
}
```